# Listview not refreshing after reload the page and cannot be removed from listview after deleting the list in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, reload, web-sql, delete-row, jquery-mobile-listview

Hello I am attending the create and retrieve the data using [HTML 5 Web sql Database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm).Its functionality working correctly i expected.

When i showing the results in next page in list view it showing correctly but when i refresh the page list view not showing only go to previous page then come this page its working and also i added a delete button in list view when i click the delete button records are deleted.but the list not remove from the list view only go to previous then come this page only removed. How to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Clientside Database</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-     1.3.2.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div data-role=page id="home">
<div data-role=header>
    <h1>ClientSide Database</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">


        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="firstname">FirstName:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" class="required" />
        </li>

          <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="lastname">LastName:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" class="required" />
        </li>

           <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required" />
        </li>


         <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="date">Date of Birth:</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="" class="required" />
        </li>

         <li >
        <input value = "SUBMIT" type = "button" name="submit" id="submit" />
        <input type="button" value="view" id="view"/>
        </li>
        </ul>

</div><!-- /content -->
 </div>
 <div data-role="page" id="dataview" data-add-back-btn=true>
 <div data-role="header">
  <h1>List of customers</h1>
  </div>

 <div data-role="content">

 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
  </html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var db = openDatabase("MyDatabase","1.0","My ClientSide Database",1000000);
  $("#submit").bind('click',function(e){
db.transaction(function(transaction){
var sql = "CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS clientrecords " +
    " (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "fname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " + 
    "lname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL," + 
    "email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ," + 
    "date VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)"   
transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, function ()
   { 
     console.log("Table Created Successfully");
      }, error);  
    });
     var lname = $("#firstname").val ();
     var fname = $("#lastname").val ();
     var email =$("#email").val();
     var date  =$("#date").val();


 db.transaction (function (transaction) 
 {
     var sql = "INSERT INTO clientrecords (lname, fname,email,date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
transaction.executeSql (sql, [lname, fname,email,date], function ()
{ 
console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
}, error);
  });

  });

  $("#view").bind ("click", function (event)
{
  db.transaction (function (transaction) 
 {
var sql = "SELECT * FROM clientrecords";
transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, 
function (transaction, result)
{
  var html = "<ul data-icon=false data-split-icon=delete data-split-theme=d>";
  if (result.rows.length)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
    {
      var row = result.rows.item (i);
      var lname = row.lname;
      var fname = row.fname;
      var email = row.email;
      var date = row.date;
      var id = row.id;
      html += "<li " + "id=" + id + ">";
      html +='<a href="#"><h2>' + lname + "&nbsp;" + fname + '</h2><p>'+ email +'</p> <div class="ui-li-aside"><p>'+date+'</p></div></a> <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>';
      html +='</li>';

    }
  }
  else
  {
    html += "<li> No customer </li>";
  }

  html += "</ul>";

  $("#dataview").unbind ().bind ("pagebeforeshow", function ()
  {
    var $content = $("#dataview div:jqmData(role=content)");
    $content.html (html);
    var $ul = $content.find ("ul");
    $ul.listview ();


     $(".delete").bind ("swiperight", function (event)
    {

      var listitem = $(this).parent( "li" ).attr ("id");
      if (!listitem) return;

      $(listitem).remove ();

      db.transaction (function (transaction) 
      {
        var sql = "DELETE FROM clientrecords WHERE id=?";
        transaction.executeSql (sql, [id], function ()
        { 
          console.log("Employee Records deleted");
        }, error);
      });
    });     
  });

  $.mobile.changePage ($("#dataview"));

}, error);
     });
  });

   function ok ()
  {
   }

   function error (transaction, err) 
  {
   alert ("DB error : " + err.message);
  return false;
  }
```

Comment: this `$(".delete").bind ("swiperight", function (event)` to this `$(document).on("swiperight", ".delete" , function (event)` because its dynamically added. Also this `$("#dataview").unbind ().bind ("pagebeforeshow", function ()`  to `$("#dataview").on("pagebeforeshow", function ()`.

Comment: Can you post your code on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @SergePashkevich I fix my issues.

Comment: As I know it is a good practice to post your answer here separately and accept it. People can have the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 0):

$('#your_ul_id').listview('refresh');

Just add this to your deleting event. You don't have it. 
Remember, if you append or remove something, you use the above code.
If you just want to refresh it without appending, use the following:

$('#your_ul_id').listview();